# How to crop plot map on GeoPandas?

Tags: python, visualization, geopandas

So I have this code using python and GeoPandas:

```
import geopandas as gpd

countries = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
# plot map on axis
countries[countries["name"]== "Brazil"].plot(color="lightgrey",ax=ax)
```

This produces this plot:
[image]

I would like to crop using a specific latitude and longitude, but cant find the correct parameters.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Geopandas uses matplotlib under the hood, so you can use [the functions that control the axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html) for this.

For example, cropping to latitudes -15 to -5:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))

ax.set_ylim((-15, -5))

countries[countries["name"]== "Brazil"].plot(color="lightgrey",ax=ax)
```

[image: Crop result for Brazil example]